# How to automate git backporting using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In git we have 2 branches, `main` and `staging`. My requirement is if I merge any changes in `staging` branch it will automatically need to merge those new changes to `main` branch.

I am using GitHub Actions to implement this:

```yaml
name: Backport
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - closed
      - labeled

jobs:
  backport:
    name: Backport
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Only react to merged PRs for security reasons.
    # See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target.
    if: >
      github.event.pull_request.merged
      && (
        github.event.action == 'closed'
        || (
          github.event.action == 'labeled'
          && contains(github.event.label.name, 'backport')
        )
      )
    steps:
      - uses: tibdex/backport@v2
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GIT_BACKPORT }}
```

If I merge any changes to `staging` branch it's triggering the workflow, but I am getting below error and it's failing to merge new changes to `main` branch:

```
  /usr/bin/git switch main
  Already on 'main'
  Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
  /usr/bin/git switch --create backport-16-to-main
  Switched to a new branch 'backport-16-to-main'
  /usr/bin/git cherry-pick -x c3434caf8741axxxxxx
  error: commit c3434cafxxxxxxx is a merge but no -m option was given.
  fatal: cherry-pick failed
  /usr/bin/git cherry-pick --abort
  error: no cherry-pick or revert in progress
  fatal: cherry-pick failed
  Error: Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

Comment: Is LCA of `main` and `staging` one of `main` and `staging`? If that were the case, the problem would be simple.

Comment: LCA of `main` and `staging` is `main`,staging is like release branch, if any merge happens on stage then those changes need to merge to main also.

Comment: I found [an implement](https://github.com/kaikaibenkai/api-node-sdk/blob/dc34d582cfb92f957c17e48acf1329051526f8fa/.github/workflows/release.yml#L17) I wrote days ago, my `main` means your `staging` and my `stable` means your `main`

Answer (score 0):

> LCA of main and staging is main

just like:

```
··· * ----- * ----- *
            |       |
          main   staging
```

you can write:

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
  - run: |
      git checkout -b stable origin/main
      git merge --ff-only origin/staging
      git push origin main
```

However, if LCA of `main` and `staging` is not `main`, the job will fail.